# Unexpected value 'ActivatedRoute' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.while adding ActivatedRoute

Tags: angular

I am trying to import ActivatedRoute module in an Angular Client app . I am getting below error. I am not sure what I am missing. I did not face any problem while importing any other module.

Unexpected value 'ActivatedRoute' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

My AppModule.ts is

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { InfiniteScrollModule } from 'ngx-infinite-scroll';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest
  } from '@angular/common/http';

// import { NgxSpinnerModule } from 'ngx-spinner';

// used to create fake backend
import { fakeBackendProvider } from './_helpers';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { routing }        from './app.routing';

import { AlertComponent } from './_directives';
import { AuthGuard } from './_guards';
import { ErrorInterceptor } from './_helpers';
import { AlertService, AuthenticationService, UserService } from './_services';
import { HomeComponent } from './home';
import { LoginComponent } from './login';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register';;
import { LogoutComponent } from './logout/logout.component'
;
import { PostComponent } from './post/post.component'
;
import { CommentComponent } from './comment/comment.component'
;
import { AnswersComponent } from './answers/answers.component'
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        routing,
        InfiniteScrollModule,
        ActivatedRoute
        // NgxSpinnerModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AlertComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        RegisterComponent,
        LogoutComponent
,
        LogoutComponent ,
        PostComponent ,
        CommentComponent ,
        AnswersComponent ],
    providers: [
        AuthGuard,
        AlertService,
        AuthenticationService,
        UserService,
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: XhrInterceptor, multi: true },
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true }

        // provider used to create fake backend
        // fakeBackendProvider
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: ActivatedRoute isn't a module. You import it into components. You only need to import the RouterModule in your app module, which I assume is coming from `routing` in your example.

Comment: @KurtHamilton Thanks!